# GUILayout.BeginScrollView - How to load images downloaded from http

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

My Question Is Regarding With Unity3D.
I have a list of image urls downloaded from http.
I just want to show these images on GUILayout.BeginScrollView. 
I searched About it from few days but not get any appropriate answer.

Here is my code Sample,

```
public void OnSuccess(object responseFromServer)
{
  File imageObj = (File)responseFromServer;
  IList<File.Image> imageList = imageObj.GetFileList();
  for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++)
   {
    Debug.Log ("Downloaded Image Url Is  : " + imageList[i].GetUrl());
   }
}
```

Now, I have a number of Image Urls, But how to show images of these urls on GUILayout.BeginScrollview. 
Thanx for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Akshay hi, You are all set, just try this ...

if you have a list of images , then add them in an IList, got it, and use texture2D inOrder to show these images to scrollview. Look at this , i think its your answer...

```
public void OnSuccess(object responseFromServer)
{
  File imageObj = (File)responseFromServer;
  IList<File.Image> imageList = imageObj.GetFileList();
  for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++)
   {
    Debug.Log ("Downloaded Image Url Is  : " + imageList[i].GetUrl());
// just add this in your callBack response. ClassName shoud be where you want to show your // images i.e OnGUI defined..
    (Your_MonoBehaviour_ClassName).GetInstance().ExecuteShow(imageList[i].GetUrl());

   }
}
```

Now write this restcall in your main class from where you want to add these images to scrollview... it is really quite simple..

```
private static Your_class_Name con = null;

    public static Your_class_Name GetInstance ()
                    {
                            if (con == null) {
                                    con = (new GameObject ("Your_class_Name")).AddComponent<Your_class_Name> ();
                                    return con;
                            } else {
                                    return con;
                            }
                    } 

public string ExecuteShow (string url)
        {
               string responseFromServer = null;
               StartCoroutine (ShowAllImages (url));
               return responseFromServer;
        }

            IEnumerator ShowAllImages (string uri)
            {
                    IEnumerator e = executeShowAll (uri);
                    while (e.MoveNext())
                    {
                            yield return e.Current;
                    }
            }


    IEnumerator executeShowAll (string url)
            {
                    WWW www = new WWW (url);
                    while (!www.isDone) 
                            {

                                    yield return null;  
                            }
                            if (www.isDone)
                    {
                      listOfImages.Add(www.texture);        
                    }

            }
```

now you are finding what's that listOfImages.. this is just a  "IList listOfImages = new List();" , the purpose behind this is.. see that..

```
//========Setting Up ScrollView====================================================        
                scrollPosition = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPosition, GUILayout.Width(155));
                if(listOfImages.Count > 1)
                {
                        for(int i=0; i<listOfImages.Count; i++)
                        {
                                Texture2D myImage = (Texture2D)listOfImages[i];
                                GUILayout.Label(myImage,GUILayout.Height(100),GUILayout.Width(100));
                        }
                }
         GUILayout.EndScrollView();
                //========ScrollView===============================================================
```

I think, you got it... coz i worked on it .. nd it is reallly very simple..

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your images in Texture2D, I have the working code for the scrollview.

```
void OnGUI()
{ 
        savedMatrix=GUI.matrix;
        scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView (new Rect (250f,10f,500f,1000f),scrollPosition, new Rect (10f, 0f, 250f, snaps.Length*150f));
        for(int i=0;i<snaps.Length;i++)
        {
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0f,10f+i*140f,250f,200f),snaps[i]);
        }
        GUI.EndScrollView();
        GUI.matrix=savedMatrix;
}
```

For texture2D from server use this

```
IEnumerator Start() 
{
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    snap.Add(www.texture);
}
```